# Reduce JPG file size it takes into memory from HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, httppostedfilebase

I have a uploading function for images.

Does anyone know how to reduce the size of a JPG image from a HttpPostedFileBase without having to save the file to the hard drive?  I'd like to keep this all in memory if possible.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadMultipleImages(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    Decimal decTN = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["TN"].ToString());
    Decimal decCN = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["CN"].ToString());

    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        String extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        String strTitleForImage = Request.Form["TitleOfImage"].ToString();
        String strDescription = Request.Form["Description"].ToString();
        Int32 intDateTaken = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["DateTaken"].ToString().Replace("-", ""));

        String strBase64Value = "";
        Stream inputStream = file.InputStream;

        // Can I reduce JPG file here in memory?

        strBase64Value = ToBase64(inputStream);
        InsertImage(decTN, strTitleForImage, intDateTaken, strDescription, strBase64Value);
        }
    });

    return RedirectToAction("Index/" + decTN + "/" + decCN);
}
```

Comment: Define "reduce in size"? Do you want to crop it, or apply heavier compression? Did you try searching, as there are hundreds of questions about image compression in C# already?

Comment: I did try to find something, but nothing that I found applied to reducing an image in a HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream without saving it to a hard drive or memory.  I want to compress it rather reducing the physical dimensions.  I want to be able to load these images, on a web page without having too much of a heavy load.  I also want to not have to save it to a directory.